# Regular expression for Word wildcard search to find parentheses including at least 3 consecutive digits

Tags: regex, ms-word, non-greedy

In the following example:

```
airspeed (AS) user (104A, 104B) device (101) vehicles (105A-C)
```

the search should find `(104A, 104B)`, `(101)`, and `(105A-C)` but not `(AS)`.

I tried using `[\(]*[0-9][0-9][0-9]*[\)]` but that found everything from the `(AS)` to the `(105A-C)`.

Comment: You need `\([^()]*\d{3}[^()]*\)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yas0Zw/1) Just escaping `(` with `\(` is enough and don't need to put in charset and to incorporate non-digit chars within it you will need `[^()]*`

Comment: `[\(]*` will match zero or more `(` characters. If the `(` is required, don't use `*`.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi  I'm getting an error in Word that ^ is not a valid special character for the Find What box

Comment: @Barmar I'm trying to cover any characters between the opening parenthesis and the three digits

Comment: That's not how `*` works in regular expressions. It doesn't match characters between, it quantifies the preceding expression. You're confusing it with the way `*` works in filename wildcards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```vb
 [(][0-9][0-9][0-9]*[)]
```

```vb
[\(][0-9][0-9][0-9]*[\)]
```

or

```vb
[(]([0-9]{3,})*[)]
```

This is *not* a **Regular expression** *Just* a **wildcard search**. This "Find and Replace" dialog box does not support the Regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

try using a capture group .*? which is non greedy

```
data="airspeed (AS) user (104A, 104B) device (101) vehicles (105A-C)"

regex = re.compile(r'\((\d{3}.*?)\)')
matches = regex.finditer(data)
output = []
for match in matches:
    output.append(match.group(0))
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, **regular expressions** cannot be used in MS Word's search(Find-Replace-Go) box, and the only way to use them in Word is to write programs in VBA to apply them.

If you are still interested in writing [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/the-regular-expression-object-model) to achieve this project, you can try to run the following code in the [VBE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary). It will **find all the text in the active document that matches the criteria and mark them in red (change them to red)**.
The criteria are as you specified: it is **the range of text with at least 3 digits inside the parentheses**.

```vb
Sub RegExFind_MarkRed_3digits_in_parentheses()

    Dim text2Found As String, d As Document, ur As UndoRecord
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "RegExFind_MarkRed_3digits_in_parentheses"
    
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    text2Found = d.Content.Text
    
    'Dim re As New VBScript_RegExp_10.RegExp, matches As VBScript_RegExp_10.MatchCollection, match As VBScript_RegExp_10.match
    Dim regEx As Object
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/the-regular-expression-object-model
                                                'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference
                                                'https://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html

    Dim matches As Object 'As MatchCollection
    Dim match As Object 'As match

    regEx.Pattern = "\([^)]*?\d{3}[^)]*?\)"
    
    regEx.Global = True

    ' Executive Search
    Set matches = regEx.Execute(text2Found)

    ' Show matching results
    For Each match In matches
        'Debug.Print match.Value
        d.Range(match.FirstIndex + 2, match.FirstIndex + match.Length + 2).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
    Next
    
    ur.EndCustomRecord

End Sub
```